# Remove chars from number dialplan asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sip

How to remove first 3 digits/letters from CALLED NUMBER. Let's say number 123456789 calls to `abc987654321`. I want to remove `abc` because in the context I have only `987654321`. I know how to cut from CALLER but don't know how to cut from CALLED(Destination) number. This is what I tried so far but nothing happen:

```
exten => _[a-z]XXXXXXXXXXXX,1,Set({CALLEDID}=${CALLEDID:3})
exten => _[a-z]XXXXXXXXXXXX,2,Dial(SIP/${CALLEDID},1)
exten => _[a-z]XXXXXXXXXXXX,3,Voicemail(${CALLEDID}@VoiceMail)
exten => _[a-z]XXXXXXXXXXXX,4,Playback(Goodbye)
exten => _[a-z]XXXXXXXXXXXX,5,Hangup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FILTER function or just do goto. You not need cut from destination,you need cut from extension.

```
exten => _[a-z]XXXXXXXXXXXX,1,Goto(${EXTEN:3},1)

exten => _XXXXXXXXXXXX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN},1)
exten => _XXXXXXXXXXXX,n,Voicemail(${EXTEN}@VoiceMail)
exten => _XXXXXXXXXXXX,n,Playback(Goodbye)
exten => _XXXXXXXXXXXX,n,Hangup
```

Please note, your dialplan still do voicemail if called part hanguped after call. Read default extensions.conf.sample to see how to deal with voicemail

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try this tomorrow since I don't have access  currently to the server and will let you know what happen.

Comment: When I make call (I dial on Zoiper )I've got: `Call from 'XXXXXXXXXXXX' (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:41432) to extension 'ABCXXXXXXXXXXXX' rejected because extension not found in context 'internal'.`. That's why I want to remove first `ABC` and then search for the number..

Comment: What you mean? That ABC is uppercase or? If I remove [a-z] I got this:`No application 'Goto{${EXTEN:3},1)' for extension (internal, xxxxxxxxxxxx, 1)`

Comment: yes, it is upercase and it is 3 chars(not one). You need replace first { with (